# Minimize Norm in $C[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonality

Find the values of $a,b \in\Bbb R$ which minimize $$\|a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)-x\|^2 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)-x)^2dx.$$

You may use the fact that $({1\over\sqrt\pi}\sin(x),{1\over\sqrt\pi}\cos(x)) $ are orthonormal in $C[0,2\pi] $.

Thanks in advance! I am very struggled with this question...

Comment: I tried expanding the square in the integral, which would make all sinx*cosx terms 0 and all sin^2 x and cos^2 x terms 1 due to orthogonality. But the remaining terms I can't cancel, and I shouldn't have to integrate, so there should be other tricks I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were given the information of a given explicit orthonormal basis. So you know that 
$$
\left\|\tfrac1{\sqrt\pi}\,\sin x\right\|=1.
$$
This means that 
$$
\frac1{ \pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2 x\,dx=1,
$$
and similarly $$
\frac1{ \pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 x\,dx=1.
$$
For the other terms, integrating by parts you get 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} x\,\sin x\,dx=-2\pi\,\cos2\pi +\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x\,dx=-2\pi 
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} x\,\cos x\,dx = 0. 
$$
So only one double product will not be zero, and
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}(a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)-x)^2dx
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(a^2\sin^2(x)
+b^2\cos^2(x)
-ax\sin x+x^2)\,dx\\ \ \\
&=(a^2+b^2+4a)\pi+\frac{8\pi^2}3.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Would you think of any other way to deal with the terms that does not involve integration by parts? Because my instructor said if I find myself doing integration by parts I'm probably using the less preferable method...

Comment: No, I cannot think of a method to show that $ \int_0^{2\pi}x\sin x\,dx=-2\pi $ that is simpler than parts, unless you want to count the "methods" of guessing the antiderivative or looking it up.